# C# Reflection with error: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm currently facing a problem, I'm trying to build a dynamic method by reflection

```cs
var attr = MethodAttributes.Public
                    | MethodAttributes.SpecialName
                    | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;
var methodGetBuilder = _typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"__Inject_From__", attr, null, new[] { typeof(Something)});
var methodIL = methodGetBuilder.GetILGenerator();
var ret = methodIL.DefineLabel();
var endIf = methodIL.DefineLabel();

methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ceq);
methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, endIf);
methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, ret);
methodIL.MarkLabel(endIf);
....
methodIL.Emit(something);
....

methodIL.MarkLabel(ret);
methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

It's equivalent in C# code

```cs
void __Inject_From__(Something arg){
  if (arg == null) return;
  // do something
  .....
}
```

My question is why I'm getting this error?

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been
> thrown by the target of an invocation.'
>
> Inner Exception
>
> InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid
> program.

The target framework of project is ".NET Core 2.0"

Comment: `.Stloc_0`, did you declare the variable first?

Comment: The general answer is what the exception already told you, you generated an invalid program. The usual things you might've done wrong is to pop something off the stack when it is empty, use a variable that isn't declared, branch to a label that hasn't been declared, or was never emitted, get the type wrong, etc.

Comment: Regarding stloc_0 and ldloc_0, can't you simply drop those two instructions completely and leave the result on the stack for the `brfalse_s` instruction?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, thanks a lot, as your questions, I removed methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0) and methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0), it works fine. It's the first time I've used IL generator, so I don't understand much of it.

Comment: In order to store a value into a local variable, you first need to declare the local variable. `.stloc_0` stores the value from the stack into the first local variable. Before this you would need to execute [DeclareLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.declarelocal?view=net-5.0), like this: `methodIL.DeclareLocal(typeof(bool));`, but if its only use is to store the value into and then immediately put it back onto the stack, you can just leave it on the stack without an explicit local variable.